# How to debug merge in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to learn how to use the MERGE operator. The following code compiles correctly:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE moto.procPM_UpdateLines
@LineId As Int = null,
@LineName As Varchar(100),
@DeleteMe As Bit = 0
    AS
    BEGIN

    MERGE moto.tblPMLine AS line
    USING (SELECT LineId, LineName FROM moto.tblPMLine) AS existsLine
    ON line.LineId = existsLine.LineId
    WHEN MATCHED AND @DeleteMe = 1 THEN DELETE
    WHEN MATCHED AND @DeleteMe = 0 THEN UPDATE SET line.LineName = @LineName
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(LineName) VALUES(@LineName);
    END
    GO
```

It's a very simple procedure, I know, but for some reason it does not seem to generate any entries when I use the following command.

```
    execute moto.procPM_UpdateLines null, 'First test', 0
```

Is there a way for me to know which of the options it is following, if at all?

---

Previous stored procedure fixed.

```
   MERGE INTO moto.tblPMLine AS T
   USING (SELECT @LineId as LineId, @LineName as LineName) AS S
   ON T.LineId = S.LineId
   WHEN MATCHED AND @DeleteMe = 0 THEN --UPDATE
        UPDATE SET LineName = @LineName 
   WHEN MATCHED AND @DeleteMe = 1 THEN --DELETE
        DELETE
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN--INSERT
        INSERT (LineName) VALUES (@LineName)    
   OUTPUT $action AS ChangesMade;
```

Now it inserts, updates and deletes, as well as returning the output.

Comment: Doesn't my answer suggest you didn't use `@LineID` variable? :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can combine `MERGE` and the `OUTPUT` clause to get some kind of an "activity report" (or debug "print statements") of what the `MERGE` is doing - maybe that'll help you get an understanding for what's going wrong.

See Adam Machanic's excellent blog post [Dr. OUTPUT or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the MERGE](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/08/24/dr-output-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-merge.aspx) that shows that technique and how to put it to use

Basically it boils down to using the `OUTPUT` clause with the `MERGE` statement to get the info on what's going on - something roughly along the lines of:

```
MERGE INTO ......
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    .......
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    ......
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    ........
OUTPUT
    $action AS dml_action,
    inserted.x AS new_x,
    deleted.x AS old_x,
    inserted.y AS new_y,
    deleted.y AS old_y;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I know how.

Comment: The link requires me to login in that site and there's no option to register. WTF! Here's an alternative url. http://dataeducation.com/dr-output-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-merge/

Answer (score 1):

```
MERGE moto.tblPMLine AS line
USING (SELECT LineId, LineName FROM moto.tblPMLine WHERE LineID = @LineID) AS existsLine
```

Pardon me as I haven't used `MERGE`. However, I don't see the code using `@LineID` variable.