# SQL Server Management Studio specifying which columns have a data type conflict

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sqldatatypes

Does anyone know how I can get SQL Server Management Studio to specify me which columns are in a data type conflict in a Merge Statement.
It's a huge table. I have already tried the following:

1. List all columns data types in both tables and see if they have the
   same data types for the origin and target tables.
2. Do a Union with the source table and the existing target table to
   see on which column it returns the conflict.

But in both cases the data types match. So I need to know which specific columns are causing the error.
SSMS just returns this message:

> *Mens. 206, Nivel 16, Estado 2, Línea 1
>   Conflicto de tipos de operandos: date es incompatible con int*

From google translate:

> Mens. 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Conflict of operand types: date is incompatible with int

Comment: Can you share the query which is causing the error?

Comment: _date is incompatible with int_ kinda narrows it down... a bit. Find all your date columns and check all of those. The issue could be on join columns. You'll find it if you do "divide and conquer" - remove half of the updated fields. If it works start checking the other half. and so on till you find the sinlge field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug merge in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898086/how-to-debug-merge-in-sql-server)

Comment: @stuartd. Interesting to use the output clause to get more info. Although in this case because it first throughs the error it doesn´t give me any output. Just still the same error message.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, I can. But I honestly don´t think it will be helpful at all since the error is in the data type, not in the query. And it has 420 lines of code...

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, If I remove even one column from the merge statement it says that the specified values ​​do not correspond to the definition of the table.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, I have to rectify. It could have helped. The problem was the order of the final Insert statement which has to be in the same order as the output table. I leave the post without solution in case osmeone comes up with a way to better debug errors in a Merge statement